# Return an image name based on an integer without using if-else

Tags: javascript

How do I return an image name based on an integer? I have an idea but it uses loads of `if` and `else` cases.

So here's the deal, I need a function which would return the name of an image based on an integer between 1 and 500. If the integer is between 1 and 30, I display image1 and from this point on I return a different image at 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, ...etc.

The first idea that comes to mind is using IFs and Elses like that:

```js
if (number >=1 && number <= 29) {
    Return image1
} else if (number >=30 && number <=49) {
    Return image2
} else if... etc
```

But this function will become huge since I'll have around 20 If Else in order to cover all possible outcomes until number 500.

The other option is to create a JSON object with key: value pairs and get the image using the integer key like this:

```js
returnImage(int) {
    let images = {
        30: 'image1',
        50: 'image2',
        75: 'image3'
    }

    return images[int]
}
```

Sadly I'm not sure how to make this work if the integer is 37 for example. I could obviously list all integers as keys but then the function would be even bigger than the if else function + there's gonna be a lot of repetition so that doesn't seem to work.

Any recommendations?

Comment: _"create a JSON object"_ — It's just an Object, in the context of JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a mathematical calculation for this:

```js
function returnImage(i) {
  let num = 1;
  if (i > 30)
    num = parseInt((parseInt(i / 25, 10) * 25 - 1) / 25, 10) + 2;
  return 'image' + num;
}

console.log(returnImage(10));
console.log(returnImage(30));
console.log(returnImage(49));
console.log(returnImage(50));
console.log(returnImage(74));
console.log(returnImage(100));
console.log(returnImage(125));
console.log(returnImage(130));
console.log(returnImage(200));
console.log(returnImage(300));
console.log(returnImage(490));
```

Comment: This is the most succinct response; given the "step-by-25 after 30" pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that works and looks great. The other answers are very good too but I think this one suits me the best.

Comment: Hey sorry for the question but I just noticed that it doesn't return the right numbers. console.log(returnImage(30)); should return image2 instead of image1 . Image1 should be returned for every integer between 1 and 29 and image2 for 30 to 49. Why is that?

Comment: @Bobimaru in that case the calculation is a bit different. I updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the keys in `images`.

```
 returnImage(num){
     let images= {
         30: 'image1',
         50: 'image2',
         75: 'image3'
     }
    for(let image in images){
     if(num <= image) return images[image];
    }
 }
```

EDIT: I would add some default image after the loop in the case that the number exceeds the max valued image.

Comment: This works great for varying ranges, but if there is a pattern then Omri's answer would be faster.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl true. I just wanted to give a different solution in the case that the ranges do change. My solution allows for more flexibility in the data.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a range.

```js
const IMAGE_FOR_NUMBER = [
  [0, 9, "one.jpg"],
  [10, 19, "ten.jpg"],
  [20, 100, "many.jpg"],
];

function getImage(n, notFound="not-found.jpg") {
  for (const [min, max, image_name] of IMAGE_FOR_NUMBER) {
   if ((min <= n) && (n <= max)) return image_name; 
  }
  return notFound;
}
```

Note that it works for disjoint ranges, too